# 403 Forbidden Access

Tags: linux, .htaccess, command-line-interface, permissions

Yesterday my supervisor mounted one of his directories onto my server. The problem is, I can't access them and I have no way of contacting him right now. When I type in the URL I get this error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /~<username>/core/ on this server.
```

I tried to cd into the "core" directory and do the following:

```
chmod -R 755 *.*
```

but, even with all the permissions changed, I still can't get access! The weird thing is, I *can* access and edit the files.

Comment: my username comes after the ~ in the path

Comment: How is the directory mounted? Is it a [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) based filesystem? Please provide the relevant entries from the Apache error logs.

Answer (score 4):

Apache needs access to every directory in the file system path to `/~<username>/core/`.

This is almost always a permission problem on `/home`.

`chmod 755 /home/` should fix it for you.

Or the SELinux issue Justin talks about.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SELinux (by default you are) then you need to allow Apache to access user home directories:

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs on
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

note that *.* does not mean the same thing in unix that it does in ms-dos and windows.  filename "extensions" aren't significant in unix like they are/were in DOS, they're just a part of the string making up the filename.

`chmod -R 755 *.*` only changes the permissions of files and directories with a '.' in their name.  To change all files regardless of whether they have a . or not, try:

`chmod -R 755 *`

even better, only directories (not plain files) need to be executable, so try something like:

`chmod -R a+rX,u+w *`

That changes all files to readable for all users, writable by owner, and also sets the execute bit on directories ("X" rather than "x").

Answer (score 0):

Do you use SELinux on the server? If you are and it's set to 'Enforcing', you may need update the context of the directory to `httpd_sys_content_t`, otherwise Apache will be denied access.

You can change the context of the directory by doing the following:

`chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t /~<username>/core`

This will change the context of the directory and it's contents to the appropriate context for the HTTPD service (ie. Apache) to work in.

More information can be found here:
http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux/

Comment: Be careful changing the directory to the "wrong" type; this can cause other problems later. Besides, there's already an easy solution by setting the appropriate boolean.